# how to compress sound waves?

Tags: sequences-and-series, compression

there is voice sound wave as series of numbers:
[image]

we sample them into discrete numbers like:
[image]
i need to compress it in half. most existing ways as simple as ignoring even samples to become half length series are changing the voice of person by higher pitched.

is there a mathematical way to do better. without changing frequency of voice too much.

Comment: Increase the gravity until your computer collapses to a black hole. That will surely compress the sound waves.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I believe that method would *destroy* said sound waves, not merely *compress* them ;)

Comment: @Math1000: I never claimed that to be a lossless compression method!!